# Arch Linux: problems building opencv with cuda; libopencv_core.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, opencv

I am currently trying to build a version of opencv, featuring cuda, on my arch linux computer. For that, I use [opencv-cuda-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencv-cuda-git/) as base version. Additionally, I modified the PKGBUILD and added additional flags to further adapt opencv to my system.

However, everytime I run the buildprocess (makepkg csri), it fails with following error message:

```
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/hdf/CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/samples/create_groups.cpp.o
cd /home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build/modules/hdf && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/bin/g++-6  -std=c++11   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-invalid-offsetof -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/samples/create_groups.cpp.o  -o ../../bin/example_hdf_create_groups  -L/opt/cuda/lib64 ../../lib/libopencv_hdf.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.4.0 
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `cblas_zgemm'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `cblas_cgemm'
make[2]: *** [modules/hdf/CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/build.make:102: bin/example_hdf_create_groups] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2523: modules/hdf/CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build'
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

My previous search suggested that this error might occur due to a linking error with cublas. Therefore I tried to add **-L/opt/cuda/lib64** and **-lcublas** to *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*. That made no difference at all.

Suggestions by another blog contained using gcc-6 instead of g++-6. That however yields another error:

```
[ 16%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_hdf_create_groups
cd /home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build/modules/hdf && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/bin/gcc-6  -std=c++11   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-invalid-offsetof -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/samples/create_groups.cpp.o  -o ../../bin/example_hdf_create_groups  -L/opt/cuda/lib64 ../../lib/libopencv_hdf.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.4.0     
ld: CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/samples/create_groups.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
make[2]: *** [modules/hdf/CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/build.make:102: bin/example_hdf_create_groups] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2523: modules/hdf/CMakeFiles/example_hdf_create_groups.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tobias/builds/opencv-cuda-git/src/opencv/build'
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

The whole output of the build process and the customized PKGBUILD file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/t03i/de1c880675c1852ba7a56a0d6936cd74)

Cuda version 9, output of nvidia-smi:

```
Sun Jan 14 14:44:13 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 387.34                 Driver Version: 387.34                    |        |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780 Ti  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 32%   27C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    624MiB /  3017MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The output suggests that you are using `libblas` and `libcublas` in parallel (one as part of a cuda-unaware `lapack`?). This might be a source of problems. Perhaps use `objdump` to search for the said symbols in both libs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Indeed I have installed `blas` and `cblas` which ar required by other parts of my system. It seems that `cblas` contains the necessary symbols. I tried to additionally link it in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but that didn't change a thing. Do you have an Idea on how to proceed from there ?

Comment: I'm no `cmake` hero, but I'd try to get rid of the `libblas` dependency. There is probably some find script you can adapt so it doesn't hook on the wrong lib. Or you hide it during building `opencv`. But I'm really outside my knowledge scope here. This doesn't even need to be related to your problem at all.

Comment: Thank you in any case! After countless hours I finally found the error.
Cmake didn't pass the linking options down correctly. I added a linking flag to LDFLAGS and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay so to close the question:

The Problem was that opencv needs both `Lapack` with the normal `blas` and `cblas` if you are using the `ceres-solver`. However, the opencv build only links `cublas`, which apparently lacks support for some needed functions of cblas.

One solution to this Problem was to manually link `cblas` by adding 
`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-lcblas` to the `cmake` call in the PKGBUILD file.

It is probably possible to circumvent this problem altogether by building all dependencies manually with forced `cublas` support. However, that is tedious and not always possible since `cublas` is only a partial port.

Thanks again to [Philippos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/216004/philippos), who helped me narrrow the problem down.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-lcblas` instead of `-cblas` in the linker flags option.

Comment: If I recall correctly that does exactly the same, since I pass it to the linker anyway.

Comment: It didn't work for me though, but it worked when I added the `l`.

Comment: Interesting, I will double check the next days, but in any case the extra l won't do any harm, so I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.